# Wy do I get an error when issuing QueryCommand in nodejs sdk v3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am using aws node.js sdk v3. I want to do a simple query on the table using dynamodbdocumentclient. I wanted to do just a test if query works on a simple music table which is provided by aws developer guide.

```
const data = await this.dynamoDBDocumentClient.send(new QueryCommand({
      TableName: "Music",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#Artist = :artist",
      ExpressionAttributeName: {
        "#Artist": "artist"

      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":artist": "Acme Band"
      },
    });
```

But when I call this I get:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

When I do a simple:

`const data = await.this.dynamoDBDocumentClient.send(newScanCommand({TableName: "Music"});`

I am getting the correct response:

````
            {
                "AlbumTitle": {
                    "S": "Somewhat Famous"
                },
                "Awards": {
                    "N": "1"
                },
                "Artist": {
                    "S": "No One You Know"
                },
                "SongTitle": {
                    "S": "Call Me Today"
                }
            },
            {
                "AlbumTitle": {
                    "S": "Songs About Life"
                },
                "Awards": {
                    "N": "10"
                },
                "Artist": {
                    "S": "Acme Band"
                },
                "SongTitle": {
                    "S": "Happy Day"
                }
            },
            {
                "AlbumTitle": {
                    "S": "Songs About Sadness"
                },
                "Awards": {
                    "N": "8"
                },
                "Artist": {
                    "S": "Acme Band"
                },
                "SongTitle": {
                    "S": "Sad Day"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ScannedCount": 3
    }```

What am I doing wrong? I don't get why I am getting en error.
````

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and according to [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html#dynamodb-example-table-query-scan-querying), the `ExpressionAttributeValues` must follow the DynamoDB JSON schema, being so, if your `artist` is a string, it should be:

```
...
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":artist": {S: "Acme Band"}
},
...
```

Adding this, worked for me.

Comment: It's not a correct answer, the OP is using Document Client, which handles DynamoDB JSON schema parsing for you in fly

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply have a typo here:

```
ExpressionAttributeName
```

It should be `ExpressionAttributeNames` (missing last letter).

However AWS-SDK is not very helpful with error messages. Use TypeScript to avoid similar issues, since it will show you, that you are using wrong field name basing on types definition.

Answer (score 0):

## Context

With the recommended query best practices from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_dynamodb_code_examples.html , **below setup only gave errors similar to yours**

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { QueryCommand, DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.REGION });
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

const command = /* ... */
const response = await docClient.send(command);
```

=>  `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

## What eventually worked:

After battling the QueryCommand with DynamoDBDocumentClient for an hour I reverted to using the simple primitive and everything started working fine with following code setup:

```
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.REGION });

const command = /* 
...
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":artist": {S: "Acme Band"}
  },
...
*/
const response = await ddbClient.send(command);
```